# multiple request "/" to asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple web form application(C# with .NET 4.5) that has some css and script.

When I call "localhost:4765/Default.aspx" every things are going right and page loads normally,
But when i call "localhost:4765", it seems some thing! makes multiple request like the below image(That capture from IntelliTrace window). all requests were made in the same time!.

It takes about 2 minutes from first request until pause on break point on default's page load.

I'm glad to say something that helps me.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I wrote below line in Route table and it's working...

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "", "~/Default.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your problem, but i sometimes(in past) copy a file to my web site root that named 'Index.html' for redirection only with blow simple content (but, if your website does not contains 'Index.html' file).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/Default.aspx" />
    <title>Redirect Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I hoped this solution be useful for your problem.